# How to make a 2 row multicolumn UICollectionView that scrolls horizontally

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I want to make a `UICollectionView` that looks like this:

```
[ - - - - - 0 - - - - - ] -> Scrolls Horizontally
[1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8]  -> Scrolls Horizontally
```

How is it done?

---

I'd prefer not to place `UICollectionView` in a `UITableViewCell` as well.

Comment: It looks like you might need to use two separate CVs, as I believe just splitting into sections would not allow for independent section scrolling.

Comment: No you can do this. Just need to implement CollectionViewFlowLayout Delegate methods. Im writing an answer now just give me a second.

Comment: @sschale I do not need independent scroll by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Make your subclass inherit the `CollectionViewFlowLayoutDelegate` protocol

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
                      layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
      sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let size = CGSize(width: defaultWidth, height: collectionView.height / 2)
    //The important thing here is the height of your item is half the height of collectionView and then your flowlayout will start to put them on top of eachother.
    // Also make sure that height accounts for section and content insets
    return size
}
```

Then just make sure in `viewDidLoad()` you set the scrolling properties of collectionView to only horizontal scrolling.

Comment: This adds one cell below the large cell and all other at the end of the view